# Detection of the text color

Tags: color

Is it possible to detect the text color in Mathematica, so that a command like this:

```
TextColor[<colored text>]
```

would return the color of the text in some way?

For example, when I input

```
G[m_] := Module[{k}, 4]
```

Mathematica colors m_ and k some greenish color(s). I'd like to know precisely what those colors are.

Comment: How was the text coloured?  Provide code that colours the text or at the very least the source of the coloured text.

Comment: @Edmund : I have added an example of such code.

Comment: does this give what you need: `textColor[x_] := Cases[x, _?ColorQ]`?

Comment: @kglr : I am not sure how to use this. When I input textColor[Module[{k}, 4]] I get {}. F1 yields "ColorQ[color] 
yields True if color is a valid color directive and False otherwise".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These styles are controlled by the `AutoStyleOptions` setting of a [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell):

```
oldLVS=CurrentValue[{AutoStyleOptions,"LocalVariableStyle",FontColor}]
oldPVS=CurrentValue[{AutoStyleOptions,"PatternVariableStyle",FontColor}]
```

> RGBColor[0.263, 0.537, 0.345]
>
> RGBColor[0.263, 0.537, 0.345]

Let's change these colors to [`Red`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Red) and [`Blue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blue):

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,{AutoStyleOptions,"LocalVariableStyle", FontColor}]=Red;
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,{AutoStyleOptions,"PatternVariableStyle", FontColor}]=Blue;
```

And, you should see that the variables are colored red and blue now:

[image]

Finally, return the colors to their old values:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,{AutoStyleOptions,"LocalVariableStyle", FontColor}]=oldLVS;
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,{AutoStyleOptions,"PatternVariableStyle", FontColor}]=oldPVS;
```

Comment: How to know the other items except `"LocalVariableStyle"` and `"PatternVariableStyle"`?

Comment: `Options[Cell, AutoStyleOptions]`